# Finding A c Value, Such That Vectors Satisfy A Certain Condition

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

> There are two vectors: $\vec{u} = 2 \hat{i} -3 \hat{j} + 4 \hat{k}$; $\vec{v} = 5 \hat{i} + c \hat{j} - \hat{k}$
>
> Find c so that $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$ is perpendicular to the z-axis

I understand, that by taking the cross product of the two vectors, $\vec{u} \times \vec{v}$ will be pointing somewhere in space. Then, I need to take that vector and transform it so that it lies in the xy-plane, or some plane parallel to the xy-plane.

Apparently to do this, one has to $(\vec{u} \times \vec{v}) \cdot \hat{k} = 0$. I don't understand how this allows us to find the c value, such that the condition is meet for the cross product. Could someone possibly explain why this is the solution?

Comment: Do you understand that $(u \times v) \cdot \hat k$ will give you an expression in terms of $c$?  Do you understand that enforcing $(u \times v) \cdot k = 0$ ensures that $u \times v$ is perpendicular to $\hat k$?  That using these two facts together means you can set an expression in terms of $c$ equal to 0 and thus it's possible to solve for $c$?

Comment: No, I believe I understand these notions. I just don't quite understand how procedure gives me a c value such the vector is perpendicular to the z-axis. In short, how do I know that this particular c-value is the c-value we need. I can do a lot of things: could probably set it equal to 5, and then solve for the c-value.

Comment: Set what equal to 5?  You have one thing that you can change or alter, and that is $c$.  When you set $(u \times v) \cdot k = 0$, you guarantee that $u \times v$ is perpendicular to $\hat k$, but you also constrain $c$ to be determined by that equation.

Comment: I guess what is confusing me is, why do we have to dot product of the vector and $\hat{k}$?

Comment: Because when the dot product of two vectors is zero, the vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: Oh, of course. I am terribly sorry for bothering you with something so trivial. Thank you very much for your help, @Muphrid

Comment: @Muphrid I would suggest that you write the comments up in an answer for Mack to accept, so that others will treat this as closed.

Comment: or @CalvinLin Mack has the option of answering his own question in 2 days

Answer (score 1):

A vector $\vec w$ is perpendicular to the $z$-axis if and only if $\vec w\cdot \vec k=0$; this follows from the angle formula for the dot product. Having computed  $\vec w = \vec u\times \vec v$  (which involves the constant $c$, yet unknown), you should write down the equation $\vec w\cdot \vec k=0$ and solve it for $c$. The equation is linear in $c$.